# With proc means, how to computed a weighted mean with BY statements?

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset in SAS:

```
Obs Date ID Diam frequency 
1 19736 H-3-10 1.92 1  
2 19736 H-3-12 1.90 1  
3 19737 E-2-10 2.92 2  
4 19737 E-2-10 3.02 2  
5 19737 E-2-16 2.34 1
```

I want to have a weighted mean of the variable `Diam` by `Date` and `ID`. Here's my current code:

```
proc means data= dataset;
    by Date ID;
    var Diam;
    weight frequency;
    output out = m_diam;
run;
```

The means I obtain are identical if I use or the `weight` statement or not !
If I omit the `by` statement, the weighted and unweighted means are different. But it gives me an overall mean, which is not what I want.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the weight isn't doing anything to the means, because inside of a by group the weights are all equal - you have no case where `frequency` has variable amounts.  `SUM` would actually be different (since SUM is sum of the weighted means), but you don't ask for that statistic.  Weights only do something if inside of a by group they are not always identical when discussing relative statistics (mean, proportion, etc.)

To see this in action, let's take your example, change one of the 2 weights to a 1.  Then we'll create DIAM_UNWT, and take advantage of the fact that you can use the `weight` option on the `var` statement to only apply a weight to a specific variable.  This will let us see that it's working - DIAM_UNWT and DIAM will have different values here, while if they are both 2s they won't.

```
data have;
input Date ID $ Diam frequency ;
diam_unwt=diam;
datalines;
19736 H-3-10 1.92 1  
19736 H-3-12 1.90 1  
19737 E-2-10 2.92 1 /*CHANGED*/ 
19737 E-2-10 3.02 2  
19737 E-2-16 2.34 1  
;;;;
run;
proc means data= have;
    by Date ID;
    var Diam/weight=frequency;
    var diam_unwt;
    output out = m_diam;
run;
```

With DIAM_UNWT the mean is 2.97 which is 1/2 way between 2.92 and 3.02.  With DIAM (which is weighted) the mean is 2.98666667 which is 2/3 of the way between them (which reflects the 2:1 weight ratio).

Comment: Thanks, now I think I understand the weight statement !

Comment: You could also use CLASS statement instead of BY (with NWAY option in PROC MEANS statement). You wont need to presort the data.

Comment: Absolutely, though that wouldn't change the result here (still would not see a difference in the weights).